# Javascript parseFloat parseInt

Tags: javascript

I'm Learning Javascript.

What does it mean to have parseFloat & parseInt functions in javascript, when in fact, Javascript does not differentiate between float and integer--there is only the Numeric data type.

Seems like they should have created parseNumber to be in alignment with their data types.

Any comments?  Maybe somebody knows the reason.  It just seems very odd.

Comment: "Seems like they should have created parseNumber" It does exist. It is called `Number()` [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)

Comment: The functions are intended to parse an input string. Only you know what the meaning of the string is: do you want to extract an integer or a decimal number from it? In addition, `parseInt` has an optional second argument...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parseInt("1.0") will be same as parseInt("1.1")
parseFloat("1.0") will be different to parseFloat("1.1")

Comment: below is also correct with more detail, but this was the first answer (and brief!)

Answer (score 1):

In `JS`, there exist `Number` not `parseNumber` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number. It works with numeric value, no matter whether it's float or int.

`parseInt` or `parseFloat` are generally used to parse `string` to number.

In decimal number i:e 10.3 the `parseInt` only return the number before decimal and discard everything after it, whereas with `parseFloat` it does consider the digits after decimal.

```js
const num = 10.3;

console.log(parseInt(num));
console.log(parseFloat(num));
```

Answer (score 1):

These functions are basically to parse string data to the relative format so according to the conditions we can use them

The [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

The [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)() function parses an argument and returns a floating point number.

```js
console.log(parseInt("1.11"))
console.log(parseFloat("1.11"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseFloat()` and `parseInt()` is javascript functions which is basically use to convert string into Float or Integer number

```js
var a = parseInt("10");
  var b = parseInt("10.00");
  var c = parseInt("10.33");
  var d = parseInt("34 45 66");
  var e = parseInt("   60   ");
  var f = parseInt("40 years");
  var g = parseInt("He was 40");

  var h = parseFloat("10");
  var i = parseFloat("10.00");
  var j = parseFloat("34 45 66");
  var k = parseFloat("10.33");
  var l = parseFloat("   60   ");
  var m = parseFloat("40 years");
  var n = parseFloat("He was 40");

 console.log("a : " + a);
 console.log("b : " + b);
 console.log("c : " + c);
 console.log("d : " + d);
 console.log("e : " + e);
 console.log("f : " + f);
 console.log("g : " + g);
 console.log("h : " + h);
 console.log("i : " + i);
 console.log("j : " + j);
 console.log("k : " + k);
 console.log("l : " + l);
 console.log("m : " + m);
 console.log("n : " + n);
```